Issue connecting my Bluetooth earphones. The device is found when in a live session (same distro)
I've been using Pop!_OS for a while and recently bought Bluetooth earphones. It's on desktop PC without an integrated Bluetooth. I bought a supposedly good Bluetooth dongle.
The Bluetooth recognizes my Nintendo Wii U Pro controller, which with the previous dongle it wouldn't, but not the earphones.
When booting Windows it recognizes both peripherals and both work fine.
Finally, I set up a bootable Pop!_OS flash drive and entered  live session. Turns out both devices were detected and worked flawlessly. On my Pop!_OS installation, though, I use the Cinnamon DE.
What am I supposed to do?
my specs:

Here's the output of some Bluetooth related console command someone told me to try:
Jun 22 06:22:56 pop-os kernel: usb 1-5: Product: Bluetooth 5.3 Radio
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 30210
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os bluetoothd[920]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth Support.
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os bluetoothd[920]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os NetworkManager[912]: <info>  [1719030177.5407] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Jun 22 06:22:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfc6d922
Jun 22 06:22:58 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
Jun 22 06:23:00 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Jun 22 06:23:00 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Jun 22 06:23:00 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Jun 22 14:23:17 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
Jun 22 14:23:17 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c24 failed: -110
Jun 22 14:23:19 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c24 failed: -110
Jun 22 14:23:19 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
Jun 22 14:23:21 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c24 failed: -110
Jun 22 14:23:21 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
Jun 22 14:23:28 pop-os systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 22 14:24:52 pop-os systemd[3053]: Starting Bluetooth management applet...
Jun 22 14:24:52 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Jun 22 14:24:53 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Jun 22 14:24:53 pop-os blueman-applet[7494]: blueman-applet 14.24.53 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading DhcpClient because its conflict has higher priority
Jun 22 14:24:53 pop-os blueman-applet[7494]: blueman-applet 14.24.53 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading PPPSupport because its conflict has higher priority
Jun 22 14:24:53 pop-os systemd[3053]: Started Bluetooth management applet.
Jun 22 14:24:53 pop-os systemd[3053]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
Jun 22 14:24:53 pop-os systemd[3053]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
Jun 22 14:25:23 pop-os systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 22 14:28:57 pop-os systemd[3053]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jun 22 14:28:59 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
Jun 22 14:28:59 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
Jun 22 14:28:59 pop-os kernel: wiimote 0005:057E:0330.0005: hidraw4: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Gamepad [Nintendo RVL-CNT-01-UC] on 8a:88:4b:80:c2:34
Jun 22 14:28:59 pop-os kernel: input: Nintendo Wii Remote Pro Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:2/0005:057E:0330.0005/input/input21
Jun 22 14:29:00 pop-os upowerd[1082]: treated changed event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:2/0005:057E:0330.0005/power_supply/wiimote_battery_8c:cd:e8:c0:5d:8d
Jun 22 14:30:46 pop-os bluetoothd[920]: src/agent.c:pincode_reply() Agent /org/bluez/agent/blueman replied with an error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply, Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Jun 22 16:56:36 pop-os systemd[3053]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Jun 22 16:56:36 pop-os systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth Support.
Jun 22 16:56:36 pop-os blueman-applet[7494]: blueman-applet 16.56.36 WARNING  DiscvManager:119 update_menuitems: warning: Adapter is None
Jun 22 16:56:41 pop-os kernel: usb 3-2: Product: Bluetooth 5.3 Radio
Jun 22 16:56:41 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
Jun 22 16:56:41 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
Jun 22 16:56:41 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
Jun 22 16:56:41 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
Jun 22 16:56:41 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 30210
Jun 22 16:56:41 pop-os systemd[3053]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jun 22 16:56:41 pop-os systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth Support.
Jun 22 16:56:42 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfc6d922
Jun 22 16:56:42 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
Jun 22 16:56:42 pop-os blueman-applet[7494]: blueman-applet 16.56.42 WARNING  PowerManager:202 on_adapter_property_changed: adapter powered on while in off state, turning bluetooth on
Jun 22 16:56:42 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Jun 22 16:56:42 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Jun 22 16:56:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
Jun 22 16:56:57 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2005 failed: -110
Jun 22 16:56:59 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2041 tx timeout
Jun 22 16:56:59 pop-os kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2041 failed: -110
Jun 22 16:57:12 pop-os systemd[1]: blueman-mechanism.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 22 17:30:54 pop-os sudo[18184]: davidspira : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/davidspira ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -b -g blue


Is your live session - where it works - a newer release, perhaps the current 24.04? Realtek 5.3 Bluetooth chips had some issues with firmware loading in the past, reason why many vendors explicitly mentioned they weren't Linux compatible. The issue has been solved late last year. You may want to install or release upgrade to the current release.

@ChanganAuto hey there. your answer seems to make sense, since I downloaded the .iso file to test the live session just few days ago. However, i ran now sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, restarted, then tried "sudo do-release-upgrade", he told me i'm supposed to use something else, which is "sudo pop-upgrade release upgrade", which i tried, but it says the current release is 22.04. pop!_os' wikipedia page confirms this, by the way

The path to release upgrade to 24.04 in Ubuntu and official derivatives is not open yet, let alone for Ubuntu based non-official spins like Pop. Checking their website there's only 22.04 indeed. That means you may be missing several updates if the live session works. Try running sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade, reboot and test.

this was the output, i don't understand any of it lol. but it didn't solve the problem https://ibb.co/ZNkjXx0

The problem is the error mentioning  a PPA that has no content for your release (no updates since 2020!) and that's enough to "break" APT. So, first step is to remove it and then properly update your system with the aforementioned commands. Again, reboot and test. And for the future do NOT add 3rd party repos without confirming they work for your specific release (or, more accurately, for the Ubuntu release your Pop!_OS release is based on).

properly updated and now the bluetooth is working. thanks a lot

Support for Realtek Bluetooth v. 5.3 chipsets has been added late 2023.
The author's Pop!_OS 22.04 was missing several important updates since the time they added an old Unetbootin PPA. As always, this situation prevents APT from working properly.
After removing the aforementioned third-party repository and fully updating the system by running sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade the Bluetooth now works as expected.
